# jQuery ValidationEngin propts are not closing

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I am using valiDationEngin for validating fields. I clicked submit button with empty fields and validation prompts appeared. After entering data, prompts are not closing. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found solution myself. I just need to initialize vallidationEngine.

```
$('form[name=ajaxForm]').validationEngine();
```